# PowerMock - IllegalStateException: Must replay Class XXX to get configured expectation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

```
@PrepareForTest({...,..., XXX.class})
...
@Test
public void testMethodToBeTested(){
    XXX mockInstance = PowerMock.createMock(XXX.class); 
    ...
    PowerMock.expectNew(XXX.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5).andReturn(mockInstance);
    mockInstance.methodWithNoReturnVal();
    expect(mockInstance.getSearchVal()).andReturn(1);
    PowerMock.replay(mockInstance);
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(objInstance, "methodToBeTested");

    PowerMock.verify(mockInstance);
}
```

Essentially, I want to test a private method: methodToBeTested(). This method instantiates an object (using the new operator) of type XXX.class and stores it into an instance variable; I mocked this object. Then, it calls methodWithNoReturnVal() via the mock, and then a getter method which I configured to return 1.

I get the error "IllegalStateException: Must replay class XXX.class to get configured expectation."

Any help is appreciated. I am still new to PowerMock and EasyMock; since I needed to use the expectNew(...) method, I made sure to use all PowerMock api inside of the test method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `PowerMock.replay(XXX.class);` in the method for Powermock to intercept the construction of the object.  See below.

```
@PrepareForTest({...,..., XXX.class})
...
@Test
public void testMethodToBeTested(){
    XXX mockInstance = PowerMock.createMock(XXX.class); 
    ...
    PowerMock.expectNew(XXX.class, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5).andReturn(mockInstance);
    mockInstance.methodWithNoReturnVal();
    expect(mockInstance.getSearchVal()).andReturn(1);
    PowerMock.replay(mockInstance, XXX.class);
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(objInstance, "methodToBeTested");

    PowerMock.verify(mockInstance);
}
```

Comment: why does it need XXX.class, but not for other cases?

Comment: @kchang, I'm honestly not entirely sure I understand why it needs it, I just know that it works and I found the documentation for it on this  site [link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)  If I had to guess why it is required, I'm assuming it has to do with the way that PowerMock is checking every new instance of the `XXX` class to see if the arguments match what is expected, but that's just a guess.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an open issue in PowerMock.

Check http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=271&q=IllegalStateException for more details.

Comment: I found the answer: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Basically, you have to pass the class into the replay and verify methods also for when you use expectNew(...)